# Alternate Definition of Quotient Category

Tags: category-theory, additive-categories

A quotient category is usually (at least from most sources I had seen) defined by something like $\mathcal C/\sim$ for some equivalence relation $\sim$, [for example in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/148579/792702). I am wondering if one can define a quotient of categories of the form $\mathcal B/\mathcal A$ for some subcategory $\mathcal B\subseteq \mathcal A$? I think this may require the categories (both $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$) to be additive (or some other properties?) to replace the operation defined on the equivalence relation, but I haven't found any reference that describes such construction. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: Consider $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ to be additive categories where $\mathcal A$ is a subcategory of $\mathcal B$. I am wondering if I can construct a "quotient category" $\mathcal B/\mathcal A$ with $F:\mathcal B\to \mathcal B/\mathcal A$ (such that $F\circ \mathbf{inc}: \mathcal A\to \mathcal B/\mathcal A$ is the zero map) satisfying the following universal property: for every category $\mathcal C$ with a functor $G:\mathcal B\to \mathcal C$ that satisfies $G(\mathcal A) =0$, there is a unique functor $\bar G:\mathcal B/\mathcal A\to \mathcal C$ such that $\bar G\circ F =G$.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. But have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_category.

Comment: What is an exact sequence of categories??

Comment: @ZhenLin Sorry I meant like having sequence $\mathcal A\to \mathcal B\to \mathcal C$ equivalent to the zero map, just as having the sequence $\mathcal A\to \mathcal B\to \mathcal B/\mathcal A$ as the zero map.

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are trying to achieve. What do you expect $\mathcal{B} / \mathcal{A}$ to be? It's just a meaningless string of symbols if you have no definition. It seems you have some preconceptions about what it should be – that's fine, but then you should tell us what those are and then maybe we can tell you whether there is a definition that fits.

Comment: @ZhenLin I updated the post accordingly, sorry about the confusion

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, for general reasons, but I doubt it is the construction you are looking for. For one thing, it is not guaranteed to be additive. Look, category theory is not about defining things by analogy for the sake of analogy. If you don't have specific examples or applications in mind to guide your inquiry it is easy to be careless and get useless answers. There is in fact a kind of [quotient of abelian categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_of_an_abelian_category) that has a universal property similar to what you ask for, but strictly speaking different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\mathcal{A}$ is an additive subcategory of an additive category $\mathcal{B}$, then there is a simple notion of "quotient category" $\mathcal{B}/\mathcal{A}$ that is often used.

It can be regarded as the special case of the quotient category $\mathcal{B}/\!\!\sim$  where, for a pair of maps $f,g:X\to Y$, $f\sim g$ iff $f-g$ factors through an object of $\mathcal{A}$.

This has the universal property that the quotient functor $Q:\mathcal{B}\to\mathcal{B}/\mathcal{A}$ is the universal additive functor from $\mathcal{B}$ to an additive category such that $Q(\mathcal{A})=0$ (i.e., like the universal property stated in the edit to the question, but with "additive" inserted everywhere).

This construction is used quite a bit in the representation theory of finite dimensional algebras. For example, the "stable module category" is the quotient of the module category by the subcategory consisting of projective modules.